# How to fill a list with similar but different objects?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, interface

I have two classes lets say "QuestionOne" and "QuestionsTwo" which are very similar and inherit from a Baseclass "Question". Now I want to write a method which fills a ArrayList with Objects of either class.

```
public ArrayList<QuestionOne> list = new ArrayList<QuestionOne>();

public void fill(QuestionOne questionOne){
list.add(questionOne);
}
```

That would be a method to fill QuestionOne objects. But I want the method to be able to fill the list with both type of objects "QuestionOne" and "QuestionTwo".

What I would like to add...I want to use alle methods of "questionOne" and "questionTwo".

How can I achieve this? Do I need an Interface? I don't know...

Comment: Replace `QuestionOne` by `Question` in your code?

Comment: What is common between the two classes?

Comment: One way of doing it is:
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList <Object>();

Comment: Can you call just methods from the base class, `Question`? or do you need to call methods that are specific to each class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you can create an ArrayList of type Question. This means that you will only be able to use methods that are defined in the Question class.

For example

```
public class Question {

    public void askAQuestion(){
        System.out.println("Im asking a question");
    }

}
```

_

```
public class QuestionOne extends Question {

    @Override
    public void askAQuestion(){
        // You can override a method. As long as it has the same name and
        // return type, it can have it's own functionality
        System.out.println("Im asking question one");
    }

    public void doSomethingElse(){
        // Because this method is not in the Question class, you cannot use
        // it in your ArrayList
    }

}
```

_

```
public class QuestionTwo {

    @Override
    public void askAQuestion(){
        System.out.println("Im asking question two");
    }

}
```

_

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
        questions.add(new QuestionOne());
        questions.add(new QuestionTwo());

        questions.get(0).askAQuestion(); // Outputs "Im asking question one"
        questions.get(1).askAQuestion(); // Outputs "Im asking question two"
    }

}
```

Comment: Thats the big Problem. Now I can't use questions.get(0).doSomethingElse(). But thats pretty much what I want^^

Comment: Could you explain what it is that QuestionOne needs to do that QuestionTwo doesn't? (and vice versa) thanks

Comment: Please note that, in general, the instanceof keyword should only be used as a last resort. Overriding methods is usually prerferable. More information can be found at http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31

Answer (score 6):

Make an `ArrayList<Question>` and fill it up that way. Although you'll only have the interface available, that the Question class exposes.

Answer (score 3):

If you use an abstract class `Question`, you will be able to use an arraylist of `Question` to store both subclass objects.

```
class Question{}
class QuestionOne extends Question{}
class QuestionTwo extends Question{}

ArrayList<Question> list = new ArrayList<Question>();

// This method will take any subclass of Question.
public void fill(Question question){
  list.add(question);
}
```

To backcast, you can use `instanceof` to compare:

```
{ //...
  for(final Question element:list){
    if(element instanceof QuestionOne){
      QuestionOne question=(QuestionOne)element;
      // Use it here.
    }
    //...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public ArrayList<Question> list = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

Now `list.add(x)` will work whenever `x` is a `Question` *or any object of a subclass of `Question`*.

In general, any time you say that a variable or parameter has type `C`, it can contain a reference to a `C` or any subclass of `C`.  This applies just as well to the parameter of the `ArrayList` `add` routine, which will look like this:

```
boolean add(Question e)
```

So you can add anything that is a subclass of `Question` to your list.

**P.S.:** Some comments are suggesting changing the parameter of `fill` also.  You can do that, but you don't have to.  It depends on your requirements.  This will still work:

```
public void fill(QuestionOne questionOne){
    list.add(questionOne);
}
```

since `questionOne` is a `Question` (as well as being a `QuestionOne`).  If you really need to, you could overload `fill`:

```
public void fill(QuestionOne questionOne){
    System.out.println("I'm adding a Type I question");
    list.add(questionOne);
}

public void fill(QuestionTwo questionTwo){
    if (questionTwo.isInteresting()) {
        // assume isInteresting is a method that is defined only for QuestionTwo
        System.out.println("I'm adding a Type II question");
        list.add(questionTwo);
    }
}
```

Usually it would be better to do something like this by adding a polymorphic method to `Question` that is overridden in `QuestionOne` and `QuestionTwo`.  But this isn't always possible.  I'm just bringing this up to point out that the parameter of `fill` doesn't actually need to change, although you might want to.